# Actionbar menu intent error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-actionbar

I look everywere and try everything I think. When I run the app, the ActionBar works fine, but when I click the "Horarios" activity button (when is in other activity) the app crushes! The only difference with te others activities is that this is the main activity.

Hear is the activity "Calendario" where the LogCat shows me the error line. I´m in this activity when I click the "Horarios" activity button at the ActionBar

```
 package com.RobertinoApps.studentmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Calendario extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendario);
}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater infl = getMenuInflater();
        infl.inflate(R.menu.menu_horarios, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId())

        { case R.id.horarios:
            //if(item.getItemId()!= R.id.horarios){
            Intent horario = new Intent("com.RobertinoApps.studentmanager.Horario");
            startActivity(horario); // <--------- Hear is the error
            return true;
            //}return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        case R.id.calendario:
            if(item.getItemId()!= R.id.calendario){
            Intent calendario = new Intent("com.RobertinoApps.studentmanager.Calendario");
            startActivity(calendario);
            return true;
            }return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        case R.id.listaDeCompras:
            //if(item.getItemId()!= R.id.listaDeCompras){
            Intent listaDeCompras = new Intent("com.RobertinoApps.studentmanager.ListaDeCompras");
            startActivity(listaDeCompras);
            return true;
            //}return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        case R.id.opciones:
            //if(item.getItemId()!= R.id.opciones){
            Intent opciones = new Intent("com.RobertinoApps.studentmanager.Opciones");
            startActivity(opciones);
            return true;
            //}return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } 

}
```

The manifest:

```
...
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.RobertinoApps.studentmanager.Horario"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Calendario"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.RobertinoApps.studentmanager.Calendario" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

...
```

LogCat:

06-12 05:28:20.090: W/dalvikvm(620): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.RobertinoApps.studentmanager.Horario }
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.RobertinoApps.studentmanager.ListaDeCompras.onOptionsItemSelected(ListaDeCompras.java:34)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2534)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:958)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:514)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:99)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-12 05:28:20.130: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-12 05:28:22.701: I/Process(620): Sending signal. PID: 620 SIG: 9
06-12 05:28:24.080: E/Trace(638): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Main Activity (Horario.java):

```
 public class Horario extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_horario);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater infl = getMenuInflater();
    infl.inflate(R.menu.menu_horarios, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId())

    { case R.id.horarios:
        if(item.getItemId()!= R.id.horarios){
        Intent horarios = new Intent("com.RobertinoApps.studentmanager.Horario");
        startActivity(horarios);
        return true;
        }return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    case R.id.calendario:
        //if(item.getItemId()!= R.id.calendario){
        Intent calendario = new Intent("com.RobertinoApps.studentmanager.Calendario");
        startActivity(calendario);
        return true;
        //}return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    case R.id.listaDeCompras:
        //if(item.getItemId()!= R.id.listaDeCompras){
        Intent listaDeCompras = new Intent("com.RobertinoApps.studentmanager.ListaDeCompras");
        startActivity(listaDeCompras);
        return true;
        //}return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    case R.id.opciones:
        //if(item.getItemId()!= R.id.opciones){
        Intent opciones = new Intent("com.RobertinoApps.studentmanager.Opciones");
        startActivity(opciones);
        return true;
        //}return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
} 

 }
```

Comment: can you send the Error Log as well as your mainActivity.

Comment: @Ali hear is the LogCat: